# Which browser was used to access SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I have come across an issue where some workflows seem to fail when the user accesses my SP2016 application using Google Chrome.

Does SharePoint log the user's browser, so that I can find out if the issue was actually caused by the Browser?

When I check the workflow instance, it shows the below:

```
An error has occurred in Workflow
For more information, please read this article: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=323543&clcid=0x409
```

We are not able to get any more details about the failure.

Comment: SharePoint Designer Workflows ? what error you are getting.

Comment: I have added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the IIS Logs to find out what browser is being used to access the site.  As far as I know this is not logged anywhere within SharePoint or the ULS.